# How to have block-images side-by-side HTML?

Tags: html

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, I'm still new to HTML but I couldn't solve this after spending a while google searching.

I'm using 2 block images to show the following.

[image]

But I'm trying to have the blocks be side by side like this.

[image]

This is the code I have.

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div class="wp-block-image">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <img loading="lazy" width="517" height="261" src="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" alt="" class="wp-image-5379">
          </a>
          <br>
          <figcaption>
            <b><u><font size="+2">
              <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png">Dashboard Example 1</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>


      </center>
    </div>

    <div class="wp-block-image">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href=https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " target="_blank " rel="noopener ">
          <img loading="lazy " width="517 " height="261 " src="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " alt=" " class="wp-image-5379 ">
          </a> 
            <br>
          <figcaption>
          <b><u><font size="+2 ">
              <a href="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png ">Dashboard Example 2</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u></figcaption></figure>
          
          
    </center>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a missing quotation mark in one of your `<a>` paths and added `display: inline-block` to both image container divs. View the snippet result in full-page to see them side by side.

Regarding your comment about changing the spacing between the images - The `<figure>` tag has these [default css values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default_figure):

```
display: block;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
```

You can override this default css in various ways. I like to create a class with the styles I want and then add that class to any element that I would like to have the new css values apply to.

An important step is to [make your css selector more specific than the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

> Use more specific rules. By indicating one or more elements before the element you're selecting, the rule becomes more specific and gets higher priority

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div class="wp-block-image" style="display:inline-block;">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <img loading="lazy" width="517" height="261" src="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" alt="" class="wp-image-5379">
          </a>
          <br>
          <figcaption>
            <b><u><font size="+2">
              <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png">Dashboard Example 1</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>


      </center>
    </div>

    <div class="wp-block-image" style="display:inline-block;">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " target="_blank " rel="noopener ">
            <img loading="lazy " width="517 " height="261 " src="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " alt=" " class="wp-image-5379 ">
          </a>
          <br>
          <figcaption>
            <b><u><font size="+2 ">
              <a href="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png ">Dashboard Example 2</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>


      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Rob,  this code runs but it doesn't solve my problem. I would like for blocks to be side-by-side.  Do you know what I can do to achieve that? Thank you !

Comment: In my answer, click the blue "Run code snippet" button and then click the "Full page" link to see them side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Any way to add more space inbetween the two boxes?

Comment: @RL_Pug - I edited my answer to include information regarding changing the spacing between the images.